# tmux session stops updating screen randomly

Tags: freeze, tmux

I use tmux 1.6-2 on a Debian 7.6 (wheezy).

I open a new session and start a long running script that gives updates in form of a progress bar and an activity indicator (spinning bar: /-\|/ ).

When I detach and reattach everything is still fine. But after some random time when I reattach the screen content is stuck. No spinning bar, no progress. I looked into the following:

- I can see in top that the process is still running
- I can successfully enter tmux commands (like new window, detach, etc.)
- I can kill the script with Ctrl-C, but the tmux screen doesn't change
- Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q (like suggested in other threads) doesn't help

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue. My process however seems to stop processing completely. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to unfreeze my tmux session by running `choose-client` command from tmux's command line `<prefix> :`

where prefix is C-b by default

I found the solution in the [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=575193#91)  (by Taisuke Yamada).

Comment: Oh man, this saved me! Thanks! Any idea how Tmux gets into this state?

Comment: No idea! Bug is a bug :)